# how to build a war file using maven in eclipse for play framework2.5?

Tags: maven, playframework-2.5

i am doing build war file using maven in eclipse for play 2.5.4 project

for that

it shows error like

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project play: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/play/app/filters/ExampleFilter.java:[40,20] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using or forcing JDK 5 but you need JDK 8 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

### EDIT

To create WAR instead of JAR, add this to your pom :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

**Example :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  ...
</project>
```

Comment: i am using java 8 only

Comment: present it build success but it creates jar file instead of war file.

Comment: i want to create a war file